# Preclude release version of Maven project

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, release

My Maven project has an automated delivery pipeline, which starts with a `mvn package` triggered by new commits on the master branch. In a later stage the current version may be released by removing the `-SNAPSHOT` part from the version, followed by a `mvn deploy`.

I would like to enforce that a snapshot version goes into the pipeline. In other words: the master branch should always contain a snapshot version. (The release version is always set automatically by the pipeline tooling.)

So, what I want is the opposite of the "requireReleaseVersion" rule of the Maven Enforcer plugin. Unfortunately there is no "requireSnapshotVersion" rule. What would be a good way to enforce the use of a snapshot version?

Comment: There will be a `requireSnapshotVersion` :). See the linked question with an alternative and link to the enhancement request.